# Bug at HitTest Falling Objects

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, collision-detection, hittest

I am making an Android Game.  The game basically is about a Hero who has to avoid the falling blocks.  And I am having a trouble here.  Somehow, even if the Hero does not hit the Block, the Hero's life will be decreased simultaneously until he dies.

The size of the stage is set to 480x800 (portrait).  Somehow, if the Hero goes to the upper left side of the stage, his life will be decreased until it gets to zero.

Here's the code: 
**fire = the block** 
 **hero = your hero**

```
//function to drop the block randomly & hitTest the Hero
function onFireEnter(e:Event):void {
    if(game){
        var fire:fx_burn=e.currentTarget as fx_burn;
         fire.y+=fire.ySpeed;

        //if HIT reset fire.Y & decrease lifepoint
        if(hero.hitTestObject(fire)){
            fire.y = randomY();
            fire.x = randomX();
            lifecount-=5;
        }
        //if fire.y>stage.height = reset fire.Y
        if (fire.y>=820) {
            fire.y=randomY();
            fire.x=randomX();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is on the code above.  If you want to see the full project, feel free to ask.  Thanks!

Comment: you need to add some flag to remember that you already decreased hero's life after hitting with specific fire and do not decrease next time

Comment: @Chermiv what do you mean by that?  I don't get the idea.  Even if the hero does not hit any fire, its life is decreasing.  Still don't get why and how to use the flag.

Comment: ok , alternative: when `lifecount` down to zero , then simply remove your `enter_frame` listener , so `onFireEnter` will not fire any more